# How to Implement Counting the Max Component of a 2D Array Representation of a Graph

Tags: java, arrays, matrix, multidimensional-array, graph-theory

Okay, so here is the scenario:

I have a 2D integer array representing my graph / matrix. If there is a connection, there is a 1, if no connection then there is a 0. Pretty simple, however I am iterating back through the array to create a subset as given. So if I have a graph:

```
{ 0 1 1 1
  1 0 1 1
  1 1 0 1
  1 1 1 0 }
```

and I pass the subset {3,1}

then I will be left with

```
{ 0 0 1 0
  0 0 0 0
  1 0 0 0
  0 0 0 0 }
```

Now my question is how to go about counting the maximum vertices in the components? So the output I want is the maximum vertices of a single component. My problem is I don't understand how I'm suppose to tell the difference in components. It's easier for me to understand on paper, but I am stumped on how to interpret it through code. I will say I am doing this in Java.

Any insight would be helpful

Edit Note:

I am trying to use BFS or some other search method to count each vertex and its connections. Then iterate over each vertex that has yet to be seen or checked, and continue. Then output the number of max components

Lets say I have a graph with connections as above before the subset given. The subset will be removed, then we are left with pieces of a graph. I then need to iterate over those pieces to find which piece has the most connections.

Comment: Are you talking about [strongly connected components](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strongly_connected_component)?

Comment: @wilx No, the subset given could separate the graph into two components. So not every vertex is reachable by each other. The base definition I'm working off of is that the initial graph is at least simple, as in no loops or multiple edges

Comment: So you start with a complete graph as one input and set of edges that should be removed to form two separate components?

Comment: It won't necessarily make two graphs. It's just a set of vertexes/connections to remove. I understand that there might a recursive solution, tracking each vertex you visit and so on. But I'm not confident behind the logic to implement it

Comment: OK, I think I still don't understand what you are actually trying to do. Maybe you should expand your explanation as to what you want to do and why.

Comment: @wilx I tried adding more clarification but I'm not sure how else to explain it without drawing it out somehow on here.